# How to call a printing function with more than two arguments on ERLANG?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

So I've wrote this program that takes 1 String Argument and print it as following:

```
-module(sayhi).

-export([sayhi/1]).

sayhi({greeting, Greeting}) -> io:fwrite(Greeting).
```

then I call the function as following (from terminal).

```
c(sayhi).

ok
sayhi:sayhi({greeting, "HELLO!\n"}).
HELLO!
ok
```

Until now everything is good.

But When I try to implement 2 arguments, I get error:
*** argument 1: wrong number of arguments

Here is my Code:

```
-module(sayhi).

-export([sayhi/2]).
    
sayhi({greeting, Greeting}, {name, Name}) -> io:fwrite(Greeting, Name).
```

When I call my function:

```
sayhi:sayhi({greeting, "Hola "}, {name, "Sam"}).
```

The program Runs successfully but does not give me the output needed.
does the problem come from my statement of calling the function?

And what if I had 3, or even 10 arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erlang has a comprehensive documentation on all of its built-in functions, such as `io:fwrite/1, io:fwrite/2, io:fwrite/3` (can be found [here](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fwrite-1)).

If you want to use the function with 1 argument, then you can call it like this:

```
io:fwrite(Greeting ++ Name). %% '++' is nothing but appending strings
io:fwrite(Greeting ++ Name ++ NextParam1 ++ NextParam2). %% You can then expand it as needed
```

When using 2 arguments, i.e. `write(Format, Data)`, then:

```
io:fwrite("~s~s", [Greeting, Name]).
io:fwrite("~s~s~s~s", [Greeting, Name, NextParam1, NextParam2]). %% You can also expand as needed
```

Comment: That was even more than I asked for, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

You can also take advantage of what Erlang calls an `iolist`, which is a list containing certain types, which can be strings, and for an iolist Erlang will output the list as one string.  For example:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).
    
sayhi({greeting, Words})->
    io:format(Words)
```

In the shell:

```
6> c(a).                                   
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

    {ok,a}

7> a:sayhi({greeting, ["Hello ", "Jim!"]}).
Hello Jim!ok
```

`io:format()` returns `ok`, and that's what you see at the end of the string.  That's not the greatest solution because you have to add spaces to your words (notice the space in `"Hello "`).  A better solution would be to automatically add spaces between words, then add a newline at the end so that the `ok` is on a separate line:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

sayhi({greeting, Words})->
    WordsWithSpaces = add_spaces(Words, []),
    io:format(WordsWithSpaces).


add_spaces([Word | []], Acc) ->
    lists:reverse([$\n, Word | Acc]);
add_spaces([Word | Words], Acc) ->
    add_spaces(Words, [" ", Word | Acc]).
```

In the shell:

```
18> c(a).
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

19> a:sayhi({greeting, ["Hello", "Jim!", "Now", "goodbye!"]}).
Hello Jim! Now goodbye!
ok
```